# AS3 extra information and properties of array included in for loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Using Flash CC

I have the following array. The first key retrieves the string "Fish" from another array.

```
static public var comboType_1:Array = 
[Constants.level_Data_Edible[Constants.currentLevel],"Frog"];
```

When I try to iterate over this array with

```
for(var i:String in hint)
    trace(hint[i]);
```

I get this result:

> Fish, 
>   Frog, 
>   function Function() {}

I debug it, it shows the array length is 2. 
I googled the function Function() {} and it produces zero hits on Google.

No one has ever heard of this function Function() {} error.

There is no third index, you can see in the array. This error prevents me from iterating over the array. #1065. Variable Function function () {} is not defined.

I'm pretty sure this is yet another Flash bug, but I just want to know the workaround.

Comment: You should loop your array like this for(var i:uint = 0; i < hint.length;i++){}

Comment: The other option is a for each loop... You can read about the differences [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcf.html).

Comment: Where is the 'hint' array assigned? You show the definition for comboType_1 array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AS3 bug (does not evaluate expressions/variables inside array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874951/as3-bug-does-not-evaluate-expressions-variables-inside-array)

Comment: Not another Flash bug, it's only another code mistake from you. You can't make any progress if you cannot face your own mistakes and instead always try to blame it on the technology you are using.

Comment: You are using static variable not as a code feature but as a lazy way to avoid writing more code. Only problem you have no clue how static variables work and when they are instantiated and you keep running into timing issues. You do know this is a code mistake and not a Flash bug or else you would show the whole code not a small smaple only meant to prove your point. Grow up.

Comment: So if it's a second bug in Flash that you have just discovered today, you are a genius, you should may be call Adobe, they will surely hire you with no doubt ! But, really, what are you speaking about ?! You show us a static var declaration, a for loop, then some texts, and we don't even know if they are from the same code, and finally it's a Flash bug ! Try to show us your whole code and we will see if you have a problem or what exactly ...

Answer (score 0):

Look it is clear that you have discovered how useful static variables can be and you use them as global variables all over your app but since you do not understand when those static variables are instantiated you are running into troubles. If you prefer to blame everything on the technology itself suit yourself but that won't fix your problem and won't make you a better coder. static variables are instantiated prior to anything else in your app so for example using another static variable like that one:

```
Constants.currentLevel
```

Is likely to produce error cos whatever the currentLevel is will be ignored anyway. Anything labelled 'current' is a red flag when instantiating static variables cos when static variables are created there's nothing current going on.

The result you are getting and the code you are showing do not match and you only do that on purpose to prove your point. You could show the whole code but you won't cos you know very well that the true mistake (your own code) will be pointed out.

Stop feeling sorry for yourself, stop blaming anything but yourself and post a real question with real code so we can show you where your mistake is.

Comment: It's a flash bug. I found the workaround elsewhere, as usual.